# When populating View Y from ListView selection in View X, why is View Y showing stale results?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await, prism

I am working on a project whereby the main window has 4 Views. Two of those views are what are vexing me.

It helps to think of the project as something like MS Outlook, where you have a list on the left and, when one entry is selected, the right pane shows the details of that view.

My project, though, is gonna have multiple MyLists. So just like in MS Word, you're opening and editing new Documents all the time, so too in this will the user be going through multiple MyLists.

What is currently happening is that the selected entry from the left pane shows up in the right pane but *one selection behind the click*. So first select shows nothing, next select shows prior selected item, next one shows prior selected item, etc etc.

I am using Prism 6. I also use [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64936/Threadsafe-ObservableImmutable-Collection) called ObservableImmutableList instead of ObservableCollection to work with my view's Listview object.

Relevant code:

MyList ViewModel:

```
public class MyListViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private MyListModel activeMyList;
    private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public MyListViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        _selectItemDelegateCommand = DelegateCommand<IList>.FromAsyncHandler(selectItem);

        //Simplified version of real method
        activeList = MyListModel.MyList.GetActiveListItem(_eventAggregator);
        ...
    }

    private DelegateCommand<System.Collections.IList> _selectItemDelegateCommand;

    /// <summary>
    /// Command associated with the selection of an item in the observableimmutablelist
    /// </summary>
    public DelegateCommand<System.Collections.IList> SelectItemDelegateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectItemDelegateCommand;
        }
        private set { _selectItemDelegateCommand = value; }
    }

    private async Task<int> selectItem(System.Collections.IList items)
    {
        var id = items.Cast<MyListItemViewModel>();

        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ItemUpdateEvent>().Publish(MyListItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemID == id.First<MyListItemViewModel>().ID).toAbstractRepresentation());     

        return await Task.FromResult(1);
    }

    private readonly object _myListItemsLock;
    private ObservableImmutableList<MyListItemViewModel> _myListItems;
    public ObservableImmutableList<MyListItemViewModel> MyListItems
    {
        get { return _myListItems; }
        private set
        {
            lock (_myListItemsLock)
            {
                SetProperty(ref _myListItems, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, I have a separate ViewModel called ActiveMyListItem that the View binds to. It subscribes to the eventaggregator

relevant code:

```
public ActiveMyListItemViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAgg) : BindableBase
{
    if (_eventAggregator == null && eventAgg != null)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAgg;
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ItemUpdateEvent>().Subscribe(setProperties);
    }
}

protected void setProperties(AbstractRepresentation abstract)
{
    try
    {
        setProperties(abstract.ID, abstract.name, [...]);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException nre)
    {
        throw nre;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I need to provide. Cheers!

#### edit

I'd like to clarify that the property MyListItems in MyListViewModel is made up of a class called MyListItemViewModel. The selected item uses a viewmodel called ActiveListItemViewModel.

In my code snippet, I didn't display this but in the actual code, both inherit from a base class since they have so many similar features. The base class, in turn, inherits from BindableBase.

I am unsure if this might be part of the problem so putting it out there.

## UPDATE

So I was able to identify the problem. In my base class viewmodel, the Properties code looks like this

```
    protected String _txtDocName;
    public String TxtDocName
    {
        get { return _myModelItem.Name; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _txtDocName, value);
            _myModelItem.Name = _txtDocName;
        }

    }
```

Changing it to this makes it work instantly.

```
    protected String _txtDocName;
    public String TxtDocName
    {
        get { return _myModelItem.Name; }
        set
        {
            _txtDocName = value;
            _myModelItem.Name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TxtDocName");

        }
    }
```

However, that is way too clunky and removes a lot of the work Prism does. What's a better way to fix this?

Comment: Create a region View X. When the list box selection is made use PRISM IRegionManager.RequestNavigate to other view.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding.

The Entry Details view is always visible. I'm not navigating to it, I'm simply populating it. Why should I use the RegionManager Navigate command?

Comment: Why is selectItems async?

Comment: Mainly because I initially grabbed the AbstractRepresentation from elsewhere in an earlier version of the code. However, I did test the code without the async await functionality and it acted exactly the same way.

Comment: Can you please reproduce the Issue in a small sample project?? Also remember mention the username in comments, so the user will be notified. For example: If you want to notify me, about something, just use @Vishal and then type your comment. That will notify me that you have replied me.

Comment: @Vishal, I'd be happy to upload a small sample project. It won't be for a couple days but I'll do it. Be great to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: what is going on here? What is the connection between your initially "relevant code" and your "problem fix"? And why does your `TxtDocName` _set_ two different fields but _gets_ a totally different one? I feel like you're not providing enough information for anyone to be able to solve your problem(s).

Comment: @MarkusHütter Your final question is bang on. I changed the variable names for my example to be abstractly descriptive but forgot to modify that one. Thanks for the catch. 

I should have put an example Property in my initial question before the edits. That was hubris on my part, assuming those were boilerplate and therefore "should" work despite my customizations. The relevant code was regarding the constructors for both views and the ICommand implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your broadcasting the fact that the property has changed but you're doing it when you're still in the middle of making the changes.

For example:

```
protected String _txtDocName;
public String TxtDocName
{
    get { return _myModelItem.Name; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _txtDocName, value);
        _myModelItem.Name = _txtDocName;
    }
}
```

`SetProperty` fires a property change notification, WPF gets the notification, queries the value and it's still the old value.  Only *after* WPF queries the new value do you actually change the value you said you already changed.

So how do you fix it?  The best option would be to rewrite the property to fire the property change after you've set all the fields.  For example:

```
public String TxtDocName
{
    get { return _myModelItem.Name; }
    set
    {
        _myModelItem.Name = value;
        SetProperty(ref _txtDocName, value);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply invoke [`OnPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736150(v=pandp.50).aspx) after you're done changing fields:

```
public String TxtDocName
{
    get { return _myModelItem.Name; }
    set
    {
        _txtDocName = value;
        _myModelItem.Name = _txtDocName;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Note that you don't have to pass anything into `OnPropertyChanged()` because the method has the `CallerMemberNameAttribute` on the `propertyName` parameter, allowing you to omit it where the property name is the same as your current property.

Comment: In your first solution, you want to use `_myModelItem.Name = value;` (not `_myModelItem.Name = _txtDocName;`), otherwise you get the old value...

Comment: @Haukinger Question poster here. Good catch, I caught it myself :)

Tomorrow I'll post more info and more of my thoughts. Mackie, great analysis, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Your answer was correct and allowed me to reintroduce the Prism eventnotifier. Thanks a lot!